# Canceling Recurring Contributions Without PayPal

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

I just noticed that our receipts for recurring contributions say "You can cancel this recurring contribution by visiting this page" with a link to PayPal's homepage and "You can update your amount by visiting this page" again, with a link to PayPal's homepage.

Almost all of our contributors are using credit cards, not PayPal.  How can I set this so our contributors can cancel a recurring contributions or increase the amount, when they are not using PayPal?

Thank you
CiviCRM 4.7.22 on WordPress 4.8.22

Comment: Do you use a different Payment Processor than Paypal for CCs? Go to Administer > System Settings > Payment Processors to see who you use for CCs.

Comment: That is not the issue.   The issue is if someone contributions with a CC and chooses to have the contribution recurring every month, how would they cancel that?

Comment: I think it is related. I believe that link is supplied via your payment processor extension. I was asking the question because you imply that that you have a different processor for CCs than you do for ACHs. But I am guessing you use PayPal for both. But either way, look where I pointed to see who is your CC Payment Processor and then I think you can track down where the link is in the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this Q&A. I think it is the answer you are looking for

[Wrong return URLs in PayPal Standard](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21264/wrong-return-urls-in-paypal-standard)