# Wrong return URLs in PayPal Standard

Tags: api, contributions, paypal

I'm using the api to process contributions from some custom pages I have created, specifically the call to civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'transact', $params).

When I use PayPal Standard as my payment gateway how do I get the Cancel URL and Success URL to point back to the pages I have created? I can't see a way to override the default urls.

The Success url is http://example.com/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&_qf_ThankYou_display=1&qfKey= However I would like to redirect to http://example.com/index.php?option=com_xxx&task=payments.success

The Cancel url is http://example.com/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&_qf_Main_display=1&cancel=1&qfKey= However I would like to redirect to http://example.com/index.php?option=com_xxx&task=payments.cancel

Do I need to create my own Payment Gateway that inherits from the PayPal Payement Gateway?
Or can I redirect the CiviCRM Tranact pages to point to the pages I need?

Comment: This question can be improved by adding details like the wrong return URLs you're currently seeing. (You can replace your site domain with `example.org` for anonymity.)

Comment: I'd also recommend running a transaction and observing the URLs your browser moves through as it completes the transaction (via browser devel tools). You may see something like `paypal.com/asdf` => `example.org/civicrm/ipn/1` => `example.org/civicrm/contribute/thanks` => `example.org/`, and those steps are all potentially significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the [alterPaymentProcessorParams](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterPaymentProcessorParams) Hook to override the parameters 'return' and 'cancel_return'.

The code looks like this:

```
function civicrm_alterPaymentProcessorParams($paymentObj,  &$rawParams,  &$cookedParams) 
{  
    if ($paymentObj->_processorName == "PayPal Standard") 
    {    
        if (!empty($rawParams['successUrl'])) {
            $cookedParams['return'] = $rawParams['successUrl'];
        }
        if (!empty($rawParams['cancelUrl'])) {
            $cookedParams['cancel_return'] = $rawParams['cancelUrl']; 
        }
    }  
}
```

$rawParams is the parameters that you passed to the payment processor in CiviCRM and cookedParams is what is passed from CiviCRM on to the Payment Site.